# MySQL Select Group By and Order By

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

Here is the SQL Statement that I am using..

```
$sql = "SELECT surname, forename, count(*) FROM people WHERE user_id='$user_id'
        GROUP BY surname ORDER BY time";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count > 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$i = $i +1;
$person[$i] = $row['surname'].'&&'.$row['forename'];
}
```

What I would like to get is all the entries from the people database relative to user_id grouped by surname and ordered by the time that they were entered in to the database. e.g.

```
12:00  Smith  James
13:00  Smith  Linda
14:00  Smith  Sam

12:30  OtherSurname  Lydia
13:30  OtherSurname  Harry
14:30  OtherSurname  Phil
```

The problem at the moment is that I only get one result for each surname.
How can I use the SELECT statement with GROUP BY and ORDER BY to get all of the entries? thank you.

Comment: please provide the table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your GROUP BY to:

```
GROUP BY surname, forename
```

Comment: This was useful, I think the answer lay in a combination of this and @codez 's answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to group by surname, you need to order by surname

```
ORDER BY surname,time
```